# A way to align the sorted structure members - month and rainfall

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Rainfall
{
    string month;
    double rainfallAmount;

    Rainfall(string m)
    {
        month = m;
    }
    string getString()
    {
        string months = month;
        return months;
    }
    double getRainFall()
    {
        return rainfallAmount;
    }


};



void sortRain(Rainfall obj[])
{
    double startScan;
    double minVal;
    int minIndex;
    for (int i = 0; i < (12 - 1); i++)
    {
        minVal = obj[i].rainfallAmount;
        minIndex = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < 12; j++)
        {
            if (obj[j].rainfallAmount < minVal)
            {
                minVal = obj[j].rainfallAmount;
                minIndex = j;

            }
        }

        obj[minIndex].rainfallAmount = obj[i].rainfallAmount;
        obj[i].rainfallAmount = minVal;



    }
    //int i = 11;
    for (int i = 0; i <12; i++)
    {

        cout << obj[i].month << " " << obj[i].rainfallAmount << endl;
    }

}

void inputValues(Rainfall obj[])
{
    double rainfallAmount;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter rainfall for month " << obj[i].month << endl;
        cin >> obj[i].rainfallAmount;
    }
}


int main()
{
    string month1 = "Jan";
    string month2 = "Feb";
    string month3 = "March";
    string month4 = "April";
    string month5 = "May";
    string month6 = "June";
    string month7 = "July";
    string month8 = "August";
    string month9 = "September";
    string month10 = "October";
    string month11 = "November";
    string month12 = "December";
    Rainfall rf[12] = {month1,month2,month3,month4,month5,month6,month7,
        month8,month9,month10,month11,month12};


    inputValues(rf);
    //displayValues(rf);
    sortRain(rf);
    //displayValues(rf);
}
```

So, per my assignment. 
**"Write a program that displays the name of each month in a year and its rainfall amount,
sorted in order of rainfall from lowest to highest. The program should use an array of
structures, where each structure holds the name of a month and its rainfall amount. Use a
constructor to set the month names. Make the program modular by calling on different
functions to input the rainfall amounts, to sort the data, and to display the data."**

The only frustrating bug is that when run, the months do not match up to the numbers at all. And I've tried virtually everything I could think of so I thought I'd post here. I believe the assignment is asking me to post the months in order of the actual numbers, but it's offset. Is there any fix for this or a perspective I'm not seeing?

Comment: You only change the rainfall amounts of the months, but you should sort the whole `Rainfall`  objects based on those amounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the operator < to return the smaller value of rainfall

```
struct Rainfall
{
    bool operator< (const Rainfall& other) const {
        return rainfallAmount < other.rainfallAmount;
    }
}
```

and right now you can use your array with std::sort

```
#include<algorithm>//std::sort is here

inputValues(rf);
std::sort(rf, rf + sizeof(rf)/sizeof(rf[0]));
for (auto r : rf)
{
    std::cout << r.month << " " << r.rainfallAmount << std::endl;
}
```

also if you make your variables public there is no need to make getters for it, everybody can access it already like I did.

Comment: Thank you both for the assistance. I will make the necessary changes to my code!